# AWS HTTP error: Connection refused for URI

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, uri

Having this error that I can't seem to get past:

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception' with message 'Error executing "PutObject" on "https://firebolt-install-aws.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/photo-1543393470-b2c833b98dce.jpg"; AWS HTTP error: Connection refused for URI [https://firebolt-install-aws.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/photo-1543393470-b2c833b98dce.jpg'](https://firebolt-install-aws.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/photo-1543393470-b2c833b98dce.jpg%27)

I've confirmed my bucket name, region, my user has a3 Full access, the bucket is not blocking public access so I really can't tell what's going on! Any help is appreciated.

```
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';
$s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'region'   => 'us-east-2',
    'version' => 'latest',
    'credentials' => [
                'key'    => "KEY HERE",
                'secret' => "SECRET HERE",
            ]
]);

if(isset($_FILES['installPics'])) {

    $file = $_FILES['installPics'];
    
    $name = $file['name'];
    $tmp_name = $file['tmp_name'];
    
    $extension = explode('.',$name);
    $extension = strtolower(end($extension));
    
    $key = md5(uniqid());
    $tmp_file_name = "{$key}.{$extension}";
    $tmp_file_path = "../uploads/{$tmp_file_name}";

    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $tmp_file_path);
    
    $result = $s3->putObject([
            'Bucket' => 'BUCKET NAME HERE',
            'Key'    => $name,
            'SourceFile' => $tmp_file_path,
        ]);

        var_dump($result);
}
?>
<div class="main-content">
    <form action="file-upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="installPics">Pictures</label>   
        <input type="file" name="installPics" multiple>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this PHP running in a ec2 instance? is so a vpc endpoint for s3 might be needed is the vpc is private.

Comment: Also you might need to enable DNS resolution/support - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-dns.html

Comment: This PHP is running on my local environment. Also, I've confirmed that DNS resolution and support in enabled.

Comment: I went ahead and tossed this on my live server to test and it uploads to my bucket just fine. So it's only having issues on my localhost?

Comment: Seems your bucket needs config update then